# How to find an owned window in a Win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi, findwindow

First, let me explain my situation:
In my Win32 app, I have a overlapped window whose HWND name is hwnd1. Now I create another overlapped window with the following code:

```
HWND hwnd2 = ::CreateWindowEx(0, L"classname", L"window_name",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, left, top, width, height,
                hwnd1, NULL, ::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

At first, I thought hwnd1 is hwnd2's parent window. But when I use "FindWindowEx" trying to find hwnd2 like below:

```
::FindWindowEx(hwnd1, nullptr, L"classname", L"window_name");
```

I can't find it. Then I discovered that hwnd1 is not hwnd2's parent but its owner. So "FindWindowEx" is invalid in this situation.
How can I find hwnd2 when I know its owner and class name and window name?

Comment: Treat it like a top level window?

Comment: You've already answered the question. You know the window has no parent, you know how to find such a window.

Comment: One possible way would be to use EnumWindows and for each enumed HWND call GetWindow with GW_OWNER to compare with hwnd1.

Comment: Be sure to read up on the differences between parent/child and owner/owned relationships. It's one of Raymond Chen's Five Things Every Win32 Developer Should Know.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.Maybe the easiest way is to traverse the windows hierarchy. But it's inappropriate to do that too frequently.

Comment: @andlabs Thank you very much for introducing the lecture of Raymond Chen's.